# PayPal RefundTransaction API (NVP) Issue

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm trying the RefundTransaction API with nvp as  `[METHOD] => RefundTransaction`
Only Common Response Fields returning as a response to PayPal RefundTransaction API Operation (NVP)
Here is the request

```
Array
(
    [METHOD] => RefundTransaction
    [VERSION] => 54.0
    [USER] => abc***xyz.com
    [PWD] => asd******asd
    [SIGNATURE] => T535*****************************************qWE3
    [CURRENCYCODE] => AUD
    [TRANSACTIONID] => 1D4*******40913KKJ
)
```

Here is the respose I'm getting.

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-11-11T11:40:57Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 3dba******fce
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 54.0
    [BUILD] => 13***072
)
```

The thing is I'm getting the response as Success, but only the common fields are there. Please help

This is how my function looks like

```
private function nvpCall($transaction_id){

            $params['TRANSACTIONID']    = $transaction_id;
            $params['REFUNDTYPE']       = 'Full';

            $nvpArr = $params ;


            $nvpreq = array();

            $nvpreq['METHOD']       = urlencode($methodName);       
            $nvpreq['VERSION']      = urlencode('54.0');
            $nvpreq['USER']         = urlencode($this->pp_pro_username);
            $nvpreq['PWD']          = urlencode($this->pp_pro_password); 
            $nvpreq['SIGNATURE']    = urlencode($this->pp_pro_signature);
            $nvpreq['CURRENCYCODE'] = urlencode('AUD');
            $nvpreq = array_merge($nvpreq, $nvpArr);

            $strReq = '';

            foreach($nvpreq as $key => $val){

                if($strReq!='') {
                    $strReq.= '&';
                }
                $strReq.= $key.'='.urlencode($val);
            }

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->api_endpoint);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strReq);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            print_r($this->deformatNVP($response));     

        }
```

**added notes**

Now i found out that it wasn't the problem with code, it was working with another username,password and signature in sandbox account though! So what might be the problem?

Comment: Can you paste the complete response from the PayPal which includes the correlation id ?

Comment: it was working with another username,password and signature in sandbox account though! So what might be the problem?